# What if someone likes cold showers?

Tags: halacha, nine-days, showering-bathing

If someone were to enjoy a cold shower as much as a hot shower, would they have any reason to take a cold shower as opposed to a hot shower during the nine days?

If they [like cold showers better](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34403), should they specifically take hot showers?

Comment: What if someone does not like taking showers should we force him to take showers during the nine days?

Comment: @GershonGold I don't think that follows from my question.  I don't think we force people to get dirty or scratch a chalkboard.  We reduce enjoyment.  Thus my question (and not yours).

Comment: I found this discussion (different from the link quoted below) to be helpful http://ohr.edu/5228

Answer (score 4):

*Any reason to take a cold shower?*

The [halocho](http://ohr.edu/1098) is that any washing for **enjoyment** is forbidden. If it is not for enjoyment, see the link quoted by eramm above (ohr.edu/5228).

*If they like cold showers better, should they specifically take hot showers?*

My guess is that we would say that [בטלה דעתו אצל כל אדם](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%90%D7%A6%D7%9C_%D7%9B%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D) – even though he likes cold showers better, he probably would not be allowed to take hot showers (which he likes less) and go against the general prohibition which applies to everyone.